# How to install bootstrappers and an MSI

Tags: visual-studio-2010, wix, setup-project

I recently changed my product's deployment.

I previously used a Visual Studio Setup Project.  Visual Studio produces a Setup.exe file that installs all of the prerequisite components (Windows Installer, .Net Framework, Visual C++ runtime) before installing from my MSI file.

Unfortunately, the Setup Project lacks some features I require (controlling services.)  I'm now using WiX to build my MSI file.  It appears the Visual Studio Setup Project will only create an installer for an MSI file it generates.  I can't ask the Setup Project to install from my WiX generated MSI file.

How can I, using Visual Studio 2010 or a third party tool, generate a Setup.exe that will install prerequisite components and my MSI file in one go?  Do I have to write my own setup application to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use the Visual Studio bootstrapper. Here's how:
http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/install_dotnet.htm
You have to do the four steps described on your WiX project.

Also check this:
[Wix and .NET Framework (prerequisites)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/427775/wix-and-net-framework-prerequisites)

And this:
[I need a WIX Bootstrapper Project that installs MY software and prerequisites](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4380252/i-need-a-wix-bootstrapper-project-that-installs-my-software-and-prerequisites)

Comment: Excelent!  I had to tweak it a bit for .Net 4 and VS2010, but that's working now.  Thank you very much!