# WiX upgrade doesn't work after changing from per machine to per user installation. How can I uninstall the old version?

Tags: wix, windows-installer, upgrade, uninstallation

WiX Toolset Version: 3.11.2.4516

To switch from a per machine to a per user installation, I changed my WiX configuration from this:

```xml
<Product Id="*" Name="$(var.ProductName)" Language="1033" Version="1.0.0.1"
  Manufacturer="$(var.CompanyName)" UpgradeCode="eec853e6-9345-4be0-908f-958f212c6f30">

  <Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" InstallScope="perMachine" InstallPrivileges="elevated" />

  <MajorUpgrade Schedule="afterInstallInitialize"
    DowngradeErrorMessage="A newer version of $(var.ProductName) is already installed" />
```

To this (remove `Package/@InstallScope` and `Package/@InstallPrivileges`):

```xml
<Product Id="*" Name="$(var.ProductName)" Language="1033" Version="2.0.0.0"
  Manufacturer="$(var.CompanyName)" UpgradeCode="eec853e6-9345-4be0-908f-958f212c6f30">

  <Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" />

  <MajorUpgrade Schedule="afterInstallInitialize"
    DowngradeErrorMessage="A newer version of $(var.ProductName) is already installed" />
```

Now the product is installed per user instead of per machine. But the `<MajorUpgrade>` doesn't work anymore. I also tried to change the `Product/@UpgradeCode` to a new GUID and add the following to my WiX config (below the `<MajorUpgrade>` element):

```xml
<Upgrade Id="eec853e6-9345-4be0-908f-958f212c6f30">
  <UpgradeVersion OnlyDetect="no" Property="OLD_SERVICE_INSTALLER_FOUND" Minimum="0.0.0.0" />
</Upgrade>
```

But that doesn't work either.

How can I uninstall the old version of my software, if I switched from per machine to per user installation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your stuck.  This is a windows installer limitation.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/major-upgrades

> Note
>
> If an application is installed in the per-user installation context,
>   any major upgrade to the application must also be performed using the
>   per-user context. If an application is installed in the per-machine
>   installation context, any major upgrade to the application must also
>   be performed using the per-machine context. The Windows Installer will
>   not install major upgrades across installation context.

Comment: Apparently it should be possible by switching to ALLUSERS context during the installation. I found this answer in another question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35064434/10069673
But I am using the [WixUI_Minimal Dialog Set](https://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/wixui/dialog_reference/wixui_minimal.html) and I don't know how to combine this answer with it.

Comment: You'd need to uninstall the per-machine instance as a pre step  outside of your MSI before ever installing your per-user install.